# Go Lang Struct Align Text

Tags: align, golang

I am using go programming

I have structs like this:

```
type person struct {  
   firstname string  
   lastname string  
   age int  
   address string  

}
```

I want it to be aligned like this

```
type person struct {
   firstname string
   lastname  string
   age       int
   address   string

}
```

and stuff like

```
const (  
    constant1 int = 1  
    c2 int = 2  
    const3 int = 3  
)
```

to

```
const (    
    constant1   int = 1  
    c2          int = 2  
    const3      int = 3  
)
```

I know align-regexp should help here, but i am unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

`M-x gofmt` does this. Here is the output applied to your examples.

```
package main

type person struct {
    firstname string
    lastname  string
    age       int
    address   string
}

const (
    constant1 int = 1
    c2        int = 2
    const3    int = 3
)
```

`gofmt` runs the external command on the buffer. Here is the output of the external command:

```
package main

type person struct {
    firstname string
    lastname  string
    age       int
    address   string
}

const (
    constant1 int = 1
    c2        int = 2
    const3    int = 3
)
```

This is with Go version go1.11.1.

You could also apply the gofmt command yourself using `shell-command-on-region`, which has nothing to do with the Emacs go mode and should show you whether the command itself works or not.

Comment: does not work, gofmt does not fix the alignment for me

Comment: `gofmt` runs the external gofmt program on the buffer. What happens if you run gofmt on the code, not via Emacs but as a standalone?

Comment: when i run it using M-x gofmt, it says buffer is already gofmted, it removes remove empty lines and everything, but does not do the alignment

Comment: Hmm. The standalone gofmt which comes with go1.11.1 does the alignment as shown in my post, except with tabs. What version are you using?

Comment: Mine is go version 1.10.3

Comment: upgraded to go1.11.1 , but alignment still wont work

Comment: Another finding, it seems its problem with Emacs. When I cat the file on terminal or run Emacs in terminal the alignment is proper, but with Emacs in GUI the alignment is not proper

Comment: Your problem seems very poorly defined. Anyway, I won't respond further here.

Comment: So if you don't know the answer you blame the question, very convenient.